# Unable to start embedded container

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to run an application with 'spring-boot:run', the application was created by a partner who is not working here anymore. It worked properly, I'v c/p the entire workspace with all the settings, etc. He was working with Eclipse Neon and me with Oxygen. The pom is as folows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ariadna</groupId>

<name>ariadnagestordemos</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>6.1.0.jre8</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
        <artifactId>zt-zip</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.81</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>ariadna-gestor-demos/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>


</build>

<artifactId>ariadnagestordemos</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1</version>
```

The error that throws me:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ariadnagestordemos 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ ariadnagestordemos >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ariadnagestordemos ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 30 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ariadnagestordemos ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ariadnagestordemos ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\WorkSpace2\ariadnagestordemos\ariadnagestordemos\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ariadnagestordemos ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ ariadnagestordemos <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ ariadnagestordemos ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Ignoring Class-Path entry jaxb-api.jar found in C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar as C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-api.jar does not exist
Ignoring Class-Path entry activation.jar found in C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar as C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\activation.jar does not exist
Ignoring Class-Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar found in C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar as C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jsr173_1.0_api.jar does not exist
Ignoring Class-Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar found in C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar as C:\Users\miguel.caballer\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb1-impl.jar does not exist
12:31:58.277 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
12:31:58.280 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
12:31:58.280 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/WorkSpace2/ariadnagestordemos/ariadnagestordemos/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2019-02-15 12:31:58.581  INFO 6744 --- [  restartedMain] com.bdr.gestorinstancias.Application     : Starting Application on CCB215 with PID 6744 (C:\WorkSpace2\ariadnagestordemos\ariadnagestordemos\target\classes started by miguel.caballer in C:\WorkSpace2\ariadnagestordemos\ariadnagestordemos)
2019-02-15 12:31:58.582  INFO 6744 --- [  restartedMain] com.bdr.gestorinstancias.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-15 12:31:58.815  INFO 6744 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4df5dfe5: startup date [Fri Feb 15 12:31:58 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-15 12:31:59.706  INFO 6744 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-02-15 12:31:59.853  WARN 6744 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol
2019-02-15 12:31:59.859  INFO 6744 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-15 12:31:59.866 ERROR 6744 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.bdr.gestorinstancias.Application.main(Application.java:25) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:206) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:992) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.075 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-15T12:31:59+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/442M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've searching for hours and I'm pretty sure the solution must be somthing really stupid. I've tryed another solutions i've found here and nothing seems to work. Any clue what's going on?
As i've said, I haven't worked in this project until yesterday, please, ask me for any part of the code that could be useful that i hadn't show.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a dependency? That class should be in (not sure on the version you need) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-coyote/7.0.27

Comment: It seems to work! But why my partner didn't have to add 'tomcat-coyote'?
Now the server is throwing me another error, but i think that could be my fault, so i have to anylize it. As soon as i have all the issues fixed I'll close the question with new info if needed. Thanks Daniele!

Comment: Not sure- maybe he used different settings and this dependency wasn't needed? In example see "Disabling the Web Server" at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html - we can disable the web connector by simply editing the `application.properties` file- if the connector is not used then spring won't try loading that class

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `pom` closely, you will see this: `<packaging>war</packaging>`, it is built to run in a separate container, for that reason they excluded all `tomcat related container`, you need put the artifact into in web container (in this case would be `tomcat`), if you want to run it with `mvn spring-boot:run`, you will have to add `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as dependency to the `pom` file.